# Java - Spring - Handling form submission with multiple results

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

This is my results html page :

```
 <h1>ResultSet</h1>
    <p th:text="'RemitterSC: ' + ${paymentOutput.remSortCode}" />
    <p th:text="'RemitterAN: ' + ${paymentOutput.remAccNum}" />
    <p th:text="'BeneficiarySC: ' + ${paymentOutput.benSortCode}" />
    <p th:text="'BeneficiaryAN: ' + ${paymentOutput.benAccNum}" />
    <p th:text="'Status: ' + ${paymentOutput.status}" />
    <p th:text="'Amount: ' + ${paymentOutput.amount}" />
```

These results are bound to my form like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="RemitterSC">Remitter
                        Sort-Code</label><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text"
                        th:field="*{remSortCode}" pattern="^[0-9]{1,}$" minlength="6" maxlength="6"
                        required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter a 6 Digit Sort Code')"
                        oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
</div>
```

The problem that I am having is that when my results page is returned, no matter how many entries there are, it only displays the first one. What do i need to do in order to display all of my results?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to iterate over a collection of results ? Then take a look at [the section on Iterations inthe Thymeleaf tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration-basics)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your problem clearly .If you want show list of data just simply loop through list of object.

```
<tr th:each="object: ${objectList}">
  //do what ever    object.something
</tr>
```

more clarification check out [this](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions)